# Monotouch no longer launching the application automatically

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

Previously when I selected "debug iPhone" in monodevelop it used to deploy as well as launch the application on the iPhone when I started the debugging.

It still deploys, but no longer launches the application on the iphone and I need to do that manually otherwise Monodevelop keeps saying "Waiting for debugger to connect"

Additional info: I am using an iPhone cable to do the debugging. It stopped working after I upgraded to mountain lion / Xcode 4.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be working. OTOH the matrix of every possible cases is quite large (and both Mountain Lion and Xcode 4.4 are very recent).

The best thing is to [fill a bug report](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com) and, beside OSX and Xcode versions, include:

- the iOS version used on the device;
- the MonoTouch version;
- the MonoDevelop version.

For the last two (and also the precise builds of OSX and Xcode) you can get them easily from inside MonoDevelop by doing **About MonoDevelop**, selecting the **Version Information** tab and copy/paste this data in the bug report.